# Grails UrlMappings with Angular html5mode Refresh

Tags: angularjs, grails, url-rewriting

I have a web-app developed in Angular with Grails at the back serving REST service calls and the root page of the single page apps as well the template html files defined the ui-router. The application has html5mode set to be true. In order have the reload to wok, I add the mapping to UrlMappings.groovy:

`"/app1/**"(view:"/app1/index")`

`/app1` is the base url of the app, `/app1/index` would be served by `grails-app/view/app1/index.gsp`, but this cause problem since all template Url's are coded in relative, which means they are also have the prefix `/app1` in Url's as well.

Ideally I'd like to have a mapping for `/app1/**.html` which still maps all template Url to html files under `web-app/app1`. But I could not find information on how to achieve this. I tried to add

`static excludes = ["/**.html"]`

But it does not work either.

Anyway to get around this other than to restructure the dynamic Url's and template file Url's to force them to have entirely different prefix?

Answer (score 0):

Your static resources are available for consumption via servlet context. So you could create a controller or a trait to mixin into existing controllers that maps to any of your static templates.

```
/**
 * Render some static content for AngularJS consumption from public folder e.g. "/templates/home.html"
 */
def renderStatic(String fileName) {
    try {
        response.outputStream << getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(fileName)
        response.outputStream.close()
    } catch (e) {
        render status: NOT_FOUND
    }
}
```

Comment: In the end, I just moved all the html template files out to a folder under web-app/templates and changed the routes accordingly.